# Can I say "medium-term", as with the adjectives "short-term" and "long-term"? Do they need prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, expressions

I would like to use an adjective to express something in between the two adjectives *short-term* and *long-term*. Does *medium-term* make sense here? What is the adjective I can use?

What preposition, if any, do I use in a sentence with any one of these three adjectives? For example:

> She told me the consequences are *_* long-term. (in a / in / at / ??? )

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U, @Guilherme. It sounds like your question about using prepositions is separate from making a choice of a word that expresses something between short- and long-term. I'd suggest posting these as separate questions so that they can be answered on their own.

Answer (score 5):

*Medium-term* exists as a phrase, but it mostly refers to public finance. In this sense, it [means](http://www.investorwords.com/3035/medium_term.html):

> 2-10 years, usually used in reference to bonds. When used in technical analysis, usually a few weeks to a few months. Also called intermediate-term.

*Intermediate-term*, another option, is also primarily associated with finance. However, people who are aware of the adjectives "long-term" and "short-term" will understand that "medium-term" or "intermediate-term" is between the two.

---

For any of the adjectives, they *describe* a property of something. The consequences *have the property of being* long-term. So you don't need a preposition with them. Compare:

> The [Noun] is [Adjective]
>
> The *cat* is *black*
>
> The *consequences* are *long-term*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use *medium-term* as an adjective.

No preposition is needed in "She told me that the health consequences of smoking are long-term."

Answer (score 0):

"In the middle term" is also used.

https://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/in+the+middle+term.html

There's a discussion about preferences here:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/middle-or-medium-term.1203522/